# button.setOnClickListener is giving me errors

Tags: android

```
 Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("Change View");
        myButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();

                }
        });
```

What exactly is wrong with this code? It gives me an error where I set the onClickListener. I also had to remove the @override above public void despite the fact that other examples have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Button` is a view, you should create [`View.OnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html):

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's easier to declare the button on main.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change View"
        android:onClick="onClick">
</Button>
```

And declare the method onClick on the Activity class

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   Context context = getApplicationContext();
   CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
   int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
   toast.show();
}
```